# Any way to run an Apex method with Admin rights or allow update to locked record from Apex?

Tags: apex

This doesn't seem like it should/could be allowed but wanted to check as I am fairly new to Apex and need to figure out how to workaround this issue.
Scenario.
We have a custom button on Quote object that when a user clickes it goes to a VFpage which calls an Apex method to update some fields on the Quote.
This works well for all cases except when the quote has been submitted for Approval.  The Approval process locks the record which prevents the Apex code from  updating some fields on the quote.  This happens for all users except Admin which makes sense since our approval process allows admins to update/unlock records submitted for approval.

Is there any method in Apex that we can use to allow this method to update fields on the quote and bypass the approval process lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call code in a class marked "without sharing" and you'll be able to update the record. This has the same effect as running the code as an administrator. My personal preference is to make a class that has many static functions meant to be run as administrator, but this isn't strictly necessary. It can be an inner class in your controller for the page, or the controller itself, depending on your exact needs.

Comment: This seems to be incorrect, even 'without sharing' `Approval.unlock(...)` fails unless the user has 'Modify All Data' permission.

Answer (score 1):

@debraSF, generally speaking you probably should avoid trying to work around security restrictions in the system. In your case, if you need to update data that's related to a quote currently stuck in an approval process, I would ask: Can you move those fields into a child object, taking them off the quote?

This way your quote can be in the approval process, and your processing and data updates can happen on a related record that's not locked.

Comment: But sometimes it's okay to bypass security controls. It really depends on the use case.

Answer (score 1):

Apex now has all sorts of lock/unlock functions on the [Approval](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_approval.htm) class. You can use these methods to

1. check for lockedness
2. if locked, unlock
3. make your updates
4. if it had been locked, re-lock

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something obvious but my hair pulling experience is that even when 'without sharing' is present execution of `Approval.unlock(<Approval Id>)` fails with below error.

The only way I was able to make it work is when the user had the 'Modify All Data' permission or by levragigin an email service workaround - see below.

> First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   04iK0000000W9cPIAS; first error:
>   INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access
>   rights on cross-reference id: []

**Email Service Workaround**

Salesforce email service allows you to execute Apex code under any user context. Therefore your code from a non-admin user could self-email the email service end-point and have some code/action executed under a user with admin privileges. Below is an excerpt of self contained class that allows recall of an approval using this approach.

**Code Excerpt:**

```
global virtual with sharing class ID_Item extends cms.ContentTemplateController implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler  {

...       

@RemoteAction
global static Map<String, Object> mApprovalRecallAction(String sContentID, String sName) {
    System.debug('>>> ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...)');

    ...

    // submitter is the person recalling, so we have permission to do so (otherwise we need to be an admin: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000iY1aAAE)
    if (oApproval.CreatedById == UserInfo.getUserId()) {        
        Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest oPWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 
        oPWR.setComments('Recalled by `' + oApproval.CreatedBy.Name + '`');
        oPWR.setAction('Removed');
        if (!Test.isRunningTest()) { // can't seem to create ProcessInstanceWorkItem records in tests
            oPWR.setWorkItemId(oWorkItemList[0].id);
            Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);
        }

        // Next the approval process needs to have a recalled action that sets `cms__Approval__c.Status = 'Recalled'` which is levraged by OrchestraCMS - but just incase these were deleted we are changing the status in apex as well
        oApproval.cms__Status__c = 'Recalled';
        oApproval.Content_Status__c = 'Recalled';
        update oApproval;
        System.debug('=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): `JSON.serialize(oPWR)=' + JSON.serialize(oPWR) + '`');
        return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => true, 'sPWR' => JSON.serialize(oPWR)};
    }
    // we assume `this.bApprovalRecalVisible` did our security checks  
    else {
        // we leverage the functionality that an email service allows us to run under a adming user
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage oMessage = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        try {
            // find our email service to use, as convention we prefixed it with class name 
            EmailServicesAddress oEmailServiceAddress = [
                SELECT e.SystemModstamp, e.RunAsUserId, e.LocalPart, e.LastModifiedDate, e.LastModifiedById, e.IsActive, e.Id, e.FunctionId, e.EmailDomainName, e.CreatedDate, e.CreatedById, e.AuthorizedSenders 
                FROM EmailServicesAddress e
                WHERE e.IsActive = true AND e.LocalPart LIKE 'ID_Item%' // `LIKE` is case-insensetive, so we keep capitialization same as class name as it's easier for search and replace 
                ].get(0); 
            oMessage.toAddresses = new String[] {
                oEmailServiceAddress.LocalPart + '@' + oEmailServiceAddress.EmailDomainName
            };
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.debug('=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): ERROR: no email service setup, `e' + String.valueOf(e) + '`');
            return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => true, 'e' => JSON.serialize('ERROR: no email service setup, `e' + String.valueOf(e) + '`')};
        }
        Map<String, Object> oParameterMap = new Map<String, Object>{'sAction' => 'mApprovalRecallActionWithAdminPermissions', 'sApprovalID' => oApproval.Id};
        oMessage.subject = '=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): `JSON.serialize(oParameterMap)=' + JSON.serialize(oParameterMap) + '`'; // using subject is not safe because SF can modify it sometimes (ex. prefixing `Sandbox`  
        oMessage.plainTextBody = JSON.serialize(oParameterMap);
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] oResults = Messaging.sendEmail(new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> {oMessage});

        System.debug('=== ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...): `oResults' + String.valueOf(oResults) + '`');

        System.debug('<<< ID_Item.mApprovalRecallAction(...)');
        if (oResults[0].success) {
            return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => true, 'oResults' => JSON.serialize(String.valueOf(oResults))};
        } else {
            return new Map<String, Object>{'bSuccess' => false, 'oResults' => JSON.serialize(String.valueOf(oResults))};
        }
    }       
}


global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail oInboundEmail, Messaging.InboundEnvelope oInboundEnvelope){
    System.debug('>>> ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...)');
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult oInboundEmailResult = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();

    Map<String,Object> oParameterMap = new Map<String, Object>{'sAction' => 'UNKNOWN'};
    try {
        oParameterMap = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(oInboundEmail.plainTextBody); 
        // expected string input format is "{'sAction': 'fooBar', 'sApprovalID': 'foo', ...}"
    } 
    catch (QueryException e) {
        System.debug('=== ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...): ERROR: `e=' + e + '`');
        System.debug('<<< ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...)');
        return oInboundEmailResult;
    }
    try {
        if (oParameterMap.get('sAction') == 'mApprovalRecallActionWithAdminPermissions') {
            String sApprovalID = (String)oParameterMap.get('sApprovalID');
            cms__Approval__c oApproval = [Select ID, c.cms__Content__c FROM cms__Approval__c c WHERE c.Id = :sApprovalID].get(0);
            List<ProcessInstanceWorkItem> oWorkItemList = [Select ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId, ActorId From ProcessInstanceWorkitem where ProcessInstance.TargetObjectId = :oApproval.ID];

            //System.debug(oWorkItemList[0]);
            Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest oPWR = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest(); 
            oPWR.setComments('Recalled by `' + oInboundEnvelope.fromAddress + '`');
            oPWR.setAction('Reject');

            if (Test.isRunningTest() == false) {
                oPWR.setWorkItemId(oWorkItemList[0].id);
                Approval.ProcessResult oPR = Approval.process(oPWR);
            }

        }

    }
    catch (QueryException e) {
         System.debug('=== ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...): ERROR: `e=' + e + '`');
    }

    oInboundEmailResult.success = true;
    System.debug('<<< ID_Item.handleInboundEmail(...)');
    return oInboundEmailResult;
}

...
```

}